# Why Math.toString() return [object Math]?

Tags: javascript

I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Description) that :

> By default, the toString() method is inherited by every object descended from Object. If this method is not overridden in a custom object, toString() returns "[object type]", where type is the object type.

So: result this code, must be **[object object ]** because `typeof Math` is `object` but , i see result is **[object  Math]**

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
console.log( toString.call(Math) ) ;
```

```js
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
console.log( toString.call(Math) ) ;
```

Tahnkyou!

Comment: type in `[object type]` does not relate to type in `typeof`.

Comment: @connexo, you may explain more?

Comment: toString shows the name of JavaScript's built-in types

Answer (score 3):

The relevant parts within the specs are:

[20.2.1.9 Math [ @@toStringTag ]](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math-@@tostringtag):

> The initial value of the `@@toStringTag` property is the String value "Math".
>
> This property has the attributes `{ [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true }`.

[19.1.3.6 Object.prototype.toString ( )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring):

> Historically, this function was occasionally used to access the String value of the `[[Class]]` internal slot that was used in previous editions of this specification as a nominal type tag for various built-in objects. The above definition of `toString` preserves compatibility for legacy code that uses `toString` as a test for those specific kinds of built-in objects. It does not provide a reliable type testing mechanism for other kinds of built-in or program defined objects. In addition, programs can use `@@toStringTag` in ways that will invalidate the reliability of such legacy type tests.

So with the current specs the result of `toString` will be `[object @@toStringTag]`.

In earlier versions it was defined as :

[15.8 The Math Object](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2)

> The value of the `[[Class]]` internal property of the Math object is "Math".

[15.2.4.2 Object.prototype.toString ( )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2)

> 4. Let `class` be the value of the `[[Class]]` internal property of O.
> 5. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings "[object ", `class`, and "]".

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is exactly what is described and expected:

> `toString()` can be used with every object and allows you to get its class.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Using_toString()_to_detect_object_class

Comment: But `Math` is not a class instance but just a regular frozen object?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies here:

> `toString()` can be used with every object and allows you to get its
>   class. To use the `Object.prototype.toString()` with every object, you
>   need to call `Function.prototype.call()` or
>   `Function.prototype.apply()` on it, passing the object you want to
>   inspect as the first parameter called `thisArg`.

Meaning when you preform:

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
console.log(toString.call(Math));
```

You are getting and printing the class - **object Math**.

taken from [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).